# Flutter Plugin With Kotlin, Activity always returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, android-activity

I am trying to access the activity reference in a Flutter Plugin written in Kotlin when I press my FAB within Flutter.

My class is `ActivityAware`

Here is the code:
Kotlin:

```
  lateinit var myActivity: Activity

    //Method called by ActivityAware plugins to fetch the activity on re-initialization
  override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {

  this.myActivity = binding.activity 
}


      //Method called by ActivityAware plugins to fetch the activity on initialization
    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {

      this.myActivity = binding.activity
  }


  //With this method is called from Flutter to check if the Activity is accessible.
  //In this case it is always returning null/ not initialized
  //It prints "FAILED AGAIN!!"
  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "checkForActivity") {

      if(::myActivity.isInitialized){

        System.out.println("I FOUND IT!!")
      }else{
        System.out.println("FAILED AGAIN!!")
      }
          return
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }
```

The dart code (Flutter):

```
//This Flutter class is run whenever you press a button to check for the Activity in Native Kotlin.
    static const MethodChannel _channel =
          const MethodChannel('sphinx_plugin');
      static Future<bool> get checkForActivity async {
        final bool isready = await _channel.invokeMethod('checkForActivity');
        return isready;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
 lateinit var myplugin: MyPlugin()

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
      myplugin = MyPlugin()
    val channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "my_plugin")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(myplugin)



  }



 //This is where I was going wrong..The reference was being lost somewhere
    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {

      myplugin.myActivity = binding.activity
  }
```

By setting:

```
myplugin.myActivity
```

I was able to find the activity reference later.
Anyways thanks :)

Comment: i had this error for hours, i blame the official docs for this. thanks you refreshed my memories